# How to declare an optional generic type in an function props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to create something similar to createAction from redux-toolkit.
I need to pass a payload type to createAction, but I don't understand how to make an optional property mandatory if it was passed.

Here is my implementation.

```
type ActionFormat<P = undefined> = {type: string} & (P extends undefined ? {} : {payload: P})

export function createAction<P = undefined>(type: string): (payload?: P) => ActionFormat {
  const actionCreator = (payload?: P) => ({ type, payload: payload });
  return actionCreator;
}
```

Creation of actions

```
 const startFetch = createAction('START_FETCH');
 const successFetch = createAction<number>('SUCCESS_FETCH')
```

Run actions

```
startFetch(); //there are no errors. No payload required 
startFetch('test'); //must be an error Payload has been submitted
successFetch(); //must be an error Payload was not submitted
successFetch(123); // there are no errors.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to spread a tuple type to a rest parameter, making the parameter either required or not based on whether `P` extends `undefined` (ie is `undeinfed` or a union containing undefined)

```
export function createAction<P = undefined>(type: string): (...payload: 
  P extends undefined 
      ? [payload?: P] // P === undefined, no parameters required, but pay be passed in.
      : [payload: P] //P does not contain undefined parameter is required
  ) => ActionFormat {
  const actionCreator = (payload?: P) => ({ type, payload: payload });
  return actionCreator;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYDFkCcC2BDYAHgAUoBeKAV1QBMIAzRVCGgPnKgG9RIAuKAM7AsTAOYBfKADIoAClIQAHsAi0BVWgyYsoAfi6T+nMHhAAbZHhr9i4gJQAoJ0rDZgUetQQpUUOFggCCHgkNBIOajpGZjZZHgh+IRFUUTt+WQA6LJNzS2soBygoBWVVGnVIrRiCotq9KABtHIsrXRsAXSgAei7i8jIKSuiWABooVGQoEyw8HAgVLHUAgEdKRACaMYAjSnccqC3oEwEBHSYMwrqofibTFvziTp7SGmQIdQn3ODRgPCYNKLaGhTPAzOYLKCIJYQVbrFiXOzkdghHyYXAELiXb6oIRQPDeNAAYQCBGwHFkzTybWKiLI7FknCg8TGlKs-FZwPsAG5LgFgJQsL58aFUMTAsBsDzxE5sbihKDgOh5nAABYcfzi4IE1CyADkAGUACowABKhoA+ugAKKGwkACV1dh5svcAkocDg7wESuAqvVJJUKLCqEoOEOWFYev1AFVCYSrfr9ZabfbHU4HPKsIrlSrZE7ul1gCqIAE8aWJlAS1hsAIMlAAHKTDlQFZrDYFTPZ3253UqISOrkFnCUXGHPG+Ktk4h3PJQFV4dSHVSCShbHCIYAqGgZ92ek4+1V5wc9Yej6B4CdYatYYozqxQADuC-GyFdq-Xm-hbo9XoPuYAjAATAAzPmPRMsWpagtAFaTosGRAA)

Comment: I don't understand why this solution doesn't work 

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kvfzr)

Comment: @СергейАнохин You are not using my solution there (you are using a previously posted answer)

Comment: thanks for the reply. If you open your solution, then there should be an error on line 14, because the type was passed on line 9. But there is no error

Comment: @СергейАнохин Your type is not what I use in my solution. It should be `(...payload: P extends undefined ? [payload?: P] : [payload: P]) => ActionFormat`